# asp.net mvc4 does compiling lead to errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build, controller

I'm relatively new to `ASP.NET`. Anyways, my question is when you compile new code into your production website is it normal to get the following error on some pages when the new compiled code is on?

> 500 error External component has thrown an exception:
>   System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005)

I usually get this on some pages as soon as I compile new code and the error can last anywhere from 3-10 minutes. Would this be because the asp.net temp files take a few minutes to notice the changes or because there is an error in my coding?

Comment: do you use IIS express to run the app?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to resolve this issue from Dec 2014, but hopefully this will help someone else in 2015.

This is unexpected behavior, but you can try to clean out your temp folder:

Delete the files in the following location to see if this helps:
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

You can also try to reinstall the framework to see if that helps.